# How can you run a python function stored in a different file

Tags: python

I know how to do this in C, but I'm not sure how to do it in python. I'm trying to make a python program which will read from an external file, then execute a function name which was read from that file. Example:

File structure:

```
main.py  
map.py  
Scripts/  
  script1.py
```

map.py contains just an array and a function to get the correct array index:

```
map = ["One","script1.function_one","Two","scrip1.function_two"]
def return_mapping(str):
  for i in range(0,len(map)):
    if str in map[i]:
      return map[i+1]
```

The functions: "function_one()" and "function_two()" are defined in script1.py.
main.py will contain something like this:

```
selection = raw_input("What function would you like to run?")
function_ptr = map.return_mapping(selection)
#This is where I don't know what the correct code is... I want to now execute
#whatever function was returned.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using `str` as an argument is not a good idea.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear here... I know how to import, but I won't know what needs to be imported. 

The above "mapping" array, is a small example. The end result is that the main.py will never know what is in map.py or script1.py. So I really need a way to execute the function returned from "return_mapping()" without knowing what the function's name is.

The goal here is main sends a request to return_mapping, and then executes the returned function, without knowing anything about it is really doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `Scripts/` directory, add a blank file called `__init__.py`

Then in your map.py file, do this:

```
from Scripts import script1

map = {"One" : script1.function_one, "Two" : script1.function_two]

def return_mapping(str):
    return map[str]
```

Comment: hmm, that's a good point. I didn't consider just executing the function from the map file... I think that'll work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In map.py, the following is simpler:

```
import Scripts.script1 as script1
map = {"One" : script1.function_one, "Two" : script1.function_two]
def return_mapping(str):
    return map[str]
```

In main.py:

```
selection = raw_input("What function would you like to run?")
function_ptr = map.return_mapping(selection)
# to call the function: function_ptr(my_args)
```

**edit**:

As mike said, you have to put an empty file called `__init__.py` in your `Scripts` directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `import`. This might be what you're looking for:

```
from Scripts.script1 import function_one, function_two
print choices:
print "function_one"
print "function_two"
selection = raw_input("What function would you like to run?")
if selection == "function_one":
    function_one()
elif selection == "function_two":
    function_two()
else:
    print "not a choice"
```

**Edit:** Given your additional requirements, consider this:

main.py

```
from Scripts.script1 import functions
print choices:
for func in script1.functions:
    print func
selection = raw_input("What function would you like to run?")
script1.functions[selection]()
```

and in script1.py

```
from collections import defaultdict
def _no_function(*args, *kwargs):
    print "No such function"

functions = defaultdict(_no_function)
def function_one():
    pass

functions['function_one'] = function_one
```

This solution permits you to call arbitrary functions without using `eval` as long as they are added to the dictionary in their respective source files. Furthermore, by using a `defaultdict` you can provide a function when the one requested is not present. Ultimately, `import` is still what you need.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I will not know what the functions are that will be executed. The idea is for a "open source" type project. So other engineers will add functions into script1.py and will update the map.py, but main.py WILL NOT change. 
Thus, main.py needs the ability to execute a function of ANY name. This is the reason for the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you should use `import`. More informations can be found here: [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Incomplete. Asker ends up with a string, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions by Mike Lewis or Simon are probably what you want, but if you **really** need to call a function whose name as is determined at runtime, you can do this:

```
 result = eval(function_ptr + '()')
```

where `function_ptr` is a string containing the function name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use a path to any file, no matter where it is:

```
import imp
import sys

mod = imp.load_source('any_name', 'path_to_your_file')
# this will get and execute your function
get_attr(mod, 'your_function_name')()
# if you want to execute load_source more than once you have to do the following, otherwise the code is not updated:
del sys.modules['any_name']
```